# struct value not being able to enter text

Tags: arrays, c, struct, variable-assignment, c-strings

How can I make user enter custom message for the msgbuf.mtext? Whenever I try to change it manually I am getting following error:

```
struct msgbuf msg
expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

What am I doing wrong?

```c
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[80];
};

int main() {

    int qid, opt;
    int mode = 0;
    int msgkey = 1234;

    qid = msgget(msgkey, IPC_CREAT | 0666); 
    struct msgbuf msg;
    msg.mtext = "hello";
    msgsnd(qid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext), 0);
    printf("sent: %s\n", msg.mtext);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C you cannot assign a string with `msg.mtext = "hello";`, use `strcpy(msg.mtext, "hello");`

Comment: ...and when you send the string message, use its length, not the size of its container. But it is unclear what `msgsnd` does, since it passes the struct address, not the string address.

Comment: @WeatherVane what if I want to input the msg.mtext with `scanf`?

Comment: Please try it and ask another question if you have problems, rather than convert this one into a rolling open-ended discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data member `mtext` is declared as a character array.

```
char mtext[80];
```

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not assign one array to another.

For strings you should use for example standard string function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`

```
strcpy( msg.mtext, "hello" );
```

Or you could initialize the data member `mtext` in the declaration of the object `msg` like for example

```
struct msgbuf msg = { .mtext = "hello" };
```

If you want to enter a string using `scanf` you can write

```
scanf( "%79s", msg.mtext );
```

or

```
scanf( " %79s", msg.mtext );
```

or

```
scanf( "%79[^\n]", msg.mtext );
```

or

```
scanf( " %79[^\n]", msg.mtext );
```

Also in this call

```
msgsnd(qid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext), 0);
```

it seems you need to use expression `strlen( msg.mtext )`  instead of the expression `sizeof(msg.mtext)`. And casting to `void *` the expression `&msg` is redundant. A pointer to any object type can be converted to a pointer of the type `void *`.

Pay attention to that the data member `mtype` was not initialized.